# How can I add a button within an innerHTML section of a HTML div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I pretty new at JavaScript & JQuery, more knowledgeable at html & css but I have something I've been working on for days and banging my head to the desk and can't figure it out. Maybe someone could help me, any hint, suggestion would be greatly appreciated!!

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="projects" class="fluid">
<button onClick="myFunction2()" class="viewprojectsclose">Close</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="viewprojects">View Projects</button>
<div id="projectsimg">
</div>
<div id="projectstxt">
</div>
</div>
```

with the following JavaScript and JQuery:

```
function myFunction() {

document.getElementById("projectstxt").innerHTML = 'some text some text some text';
document.getElementById("projectstxt").style.borderBottom = "thin solid #000" ;     
document.getElementById("projectstxt").style.display = "block";  
document.getElementById("projectstxt").style.paddingBottom ="10px";     

         document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.padding = "100px" ;
         document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.background =     "url('../Assets/img/services/image1.png')" ;
         document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
         document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.backgroundSize = "20%";
         document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.display = "block";
         document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
         document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.backgroundOrigin = "border-box";
         document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.marginTop = "5%";
;}  
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("projectstxt").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.display = "none";
;}

$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $(".viewprojects").click(function(){
    $("#projects").animate({
        height:"300px"
        });
  });
  $(".viewprojectsclose").click(function(){
    $("#projects").animate({
        height:"80px"
        });
  });   
  });
```

Basically we have 2 buttons(OPEN and CLOSE). First opens the image and text DIV and 2nd one closes.  What I'm trying to do is add another button below the image(within the div) that will redirect you to a specific page. I can add a regular button in the image DIV in HTML but when it loads the page that button appears on it by default though it should appear only when clicking on the 1st button( and opens the innerHTML). This means that I have to add it somehow in JS. If I press close and reset the div, then the button appears as it should, only when clicking on the 1st OPEN button. I have no idea what is the JS script to prevent from loading the button at first and load it only when I click on the 1st button within the JS.

Any help would be divine!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are div's `display:none` to begin with?

Comment: Instead of creating the objects with javascript, you could create them initially and set the display to none. Then set display to block when you want to show them.

Comment: @artm I can use display:none; yes but it won't load the jquery animation if I put it like this...

Comment: @aj_r yes I did that already..basically I set it to display:none in css and block in JS when it should load it but no success with JQuery animation...

Comment: Can you post your html as well? Or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: @artm I posted the html at the beginning, it's just a regular dropdown that includes 2 divs and a button

Comment: @aj_rThe thing is that if I use display:none, first time the page loads and you click to open the dropdown it will not load the JQuery. My code should create a dropdown list with images, text and buttons, JQuery will load if I reset the divs by pressing close but it will not load from the beginning if I use display:none so instead of a smooth dropdown it will just..drop.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, you want a button to appear below the image in the `div` with id `projectsimg` when the button with class `viewprojects` is clicked i.e. `myfunction()` is called?

Comment: @VivekPradhan Yes Vivek, this is what I'm trying to do. I can do it  by setting display:none for the img and text div but it will not animate the dropdown when it's first clicked. Only after I press close and then View Projects again.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nc6Law9b/ How's your code different? `display:none;` seems to work here.

Comment: @artm the code is exactly the same but if you notice, first time you click on VIEW PROJECTS it will not load the JQUERY animation. It will go directly to the height specified(in my case 300px). Then if you hit close and VIEW PROJECTS again it will load but not from the first click. And I have no idea why...it is definitely a conflict somewhere since if you remove "display:none" the animation will load from the first click. If you also use an image you can see better that it won't load from the beginning...

Comment: I'll figure this out sooner or later. Thank you guys for your answers, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a conflict because you're over-riding the `click` handler for your buttons in javascript **and** jquery. You don't have to do that at all. You should in MHO stick to Jquery and just add the appropriate DOM changes in the `click` handlers like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{      
 $(".viewprojects").click(function(){

  //Animate first
   $("#projects").animate({
     height:"300px"
     });

 //Update DOM 
 document.getElementById("projectstxt").innerHTML = 'some text some text some text';
 document.getElementById("projectstxt").style.borderBottom = "thin solid #000" ;     
 document.getElementById("projectstxt").style.display = "block";  
 document.getElementById("projectstxt").style.paddingBottom ="10px";     

 document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.padding = "100px" ;
 document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.background =         "url('../Assets/img/services/image1.png')" ;
 document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
 document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.backgroundSize = "20%";
 document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
 document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.backgroundOrigin = "border-box";
 document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.marginTop = "5%";
});


 $(".viewprojectsclose").click(function(){
  document.getElementById("projectstxt").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("projectsimg").style.display = "none";

  //Animate the div
  $("#projects").animate({
    height:"80px"
    });
 });   

 });
```

Now, I have just restructured the code that you posted in the question to give you an understanding how to fix it. The code is NOT sanitized and the syntax should be appropriately changed according to Jquery specs for simplicity and ease. It's a simple exercise that you can do on your own.

PS: I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nc6Law9b/1/) to incorporate the changes that I just mentioned and it seems to be working fine. Again, I know the Jquery syntax is not appropriate but it's deliberate. Anyway, I hope it gets you started in the right direction. Also, when using javascript and Jquery, stick to one either pure javascript or jquery as you can achieve almost all the functionality that you require her in jquery and it **is** more versatile and easy to use.

Comment: Thank you so much Vivek, it works perfectly! So basically it was loading the DOM first and then the JQuery and this is why it was the conflict. Now I understand what happened. I do have a lot to learn regarding JavaScript and JQuery and your advice is more than welcomed. I really appreciate it, you saved me from a lot of hassle. Have a great day!